# How to efficiently find the bounding box of a collection of points?

Tags: python, profiling, bounding-box

I have several points stored in an array. I need to find bounds of that points ie. the rectangle which bounds all the points. I know how to solve this in plain Python.

I would like to know is there a better way than the naive max, min over the array or built-in method to solve the problem.

```
points = [[1, 3], [2, 4], [4, 1], [3, 3], [1, 6]]
b = bounds(points) # the function I am looking for
# now b = [[1, 1], [4, 6]]
```

Comment: Share how you would solve it in Python? We could try to improve upon it. How about : `np.min(points,0) and np.max(points,0)`?

Comment: Unless your data points have some kind of ordering already, you can't do better than O(n).  So you may as well use naive min and max approach.

Comment: @Divakar That helped

Answer (score 32):

My approach to getting performance is to push things down to **C** level whenever possible:

```
def bounding_box(points):
    x_coordinates, y_coordinates = zip(*points)

    return [(min(x_coordinates), min(y_coordinates)), (max(x_coordinates), max(y_coordinates))]
```

By my (crude) measure, this runs about 1.5 times faster than @ReblochonMasque's `bounding_box_naive()`.  And is clearly more elegant.  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do better than `O(n)`, because you must traverse all the points to determine the `max` and `min` for `x` and `y`.

But, you can reduce the constant factor, and traverse the list only once; however, it is unclear if that would give you a better execution time, and if it does, it would be for large collections of points.

> #### [EDIT]: in fact it does not, the "naive" approach is the most efficient.

#### Here is the "naive" approach: (it is the fastest of the two)

```
def bounding_box_naive(points):
    """returns a list containing the bottom left and the top right 
    points in the sequence
    Here, we use min and max four times over the collection of points
    """
    bot_left_x = min(point[0] for point in points)
    bot_left_y = min(point[1] for point in points)
    top_right_x = max(point[0] for point in points)
    top_right_y = max(point[1] for point in points)

    return [(bot_left_x, bot_left_y), (top_right_x, top_right_y)]
```

#### and the (maybe?) less naive:

```
def bounding_box(points):
    """returns a list containing the bottom left and the top right 
    points in the sequence
    Here, we traverse the collection of points only once, 
    to find the min and max for x and y
    """
    bot_left_x, bot_left_y = float('inf'), float('inf')
    top_right_x, top_right_y = float('-inf'), float('-inf')
    for x, y in points:
        bot_left_x = min(bot_left_x, x)
        bot_left_y = min(bot_left_y, y)
        top_right_x = max(top_right_x, x)
        top_right_y = max(top_right_y, y)

    return [(bot_left_x, bot_left_y), (top_right_x, top_right_y)]
```

## profiling results:

```
import random
points = [(random.randrange(-1000, 1000), random.randrange(-1000, 1000))  for _ in range(1000000)]

%timeit bounding_box_naive(points)
%timeit bounding_box(points)
```

#### size = 1,000 points

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 573 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop
```

#### size = 10,000 points

```
100 loops, best of 3: 5.7 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop
```

#### size 100,000 points

```
10 loops, best of 3: 66.8 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 141 ms per loop
```

#### size 1,000,000 points

```
1 loop, best of 3: 664 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 1.47 s per loop
```

Clearly, the first "not so naive" approach is faster by a factor `2.5 - 3`

Comment: +1, but I am curious how the performance of an inline ternary statement compares to a two-element `min` call -- or, just an `if: (update assignment)`  in the case it's larger/smaller

Comment: 4 loops and 1 comparison inside each loop vs 1 loop and 4 comparisons inside the loop.  I think it's just "moving work around".  If you really want speed, you should be looking at a numba JIT or something like that.

Comment: hehehe, that was my guess too, but after your comment, I had to go back to it and measure it. Thanks for pushing me @wim. (the results are posted above)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the extraction of the bounding box faster by using numpy, in particular, if assuming that there's an additional benefit in converting your points to an array.

```py
def bounding_box_numpy(points: np.array):
    """
    Find min/max from an N-collection of coordinate pairs, shape = (N, 2), using 
    numpy's min/max along the collection-axis 
    """
    return [*points.min(axis=0), *points.max(axis=0)]


import random
points = [(random.randrange(-1000, 1000), random.randrange(-1000, 1000))  for _ in range(1000000)]
numpy_points = np.array(points)  # see the comment in the end *)
print(numpy_points.shape)  # prints (1000000, 2)
```

Then (see the earlier answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46335659/10980510 by @Reblochon Masque)

```py
%timeit bounding_box_naive(points)
%timeit bounding_box(points)
%timeit bounding_box_numpy(np_points)
```

will return profiling results

```py
136 ms ± 1.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
274 ms ± 1.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
20.7 ms ± 196 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

*) In all fairness, however, the conversion of the list of point pairs into numpy array takes hundreds of milliseconds.